# How to set 'alpha' parameter in Activation('elu') layer

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to use an activation layer in Keras with an ELU activation function and a certain value of the parameter `alpha`.

I would like to use the standard activation layer `Activation('elu')`.

The parameter `alpha` is defined for the `elu()` activation function in [keras/activations.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/activations.py#L39). It has a default value of `alpha=1.0`.

How do I pass a different value of `alpha` to the `Activation('elu')` layer?

Setting

`Activation('elu').activation.__defaults__ = (val,)`

appears to be one way to change the default value, but I do not know whether this is sensible, or indeed has the desired effect at all.

I am looking for a solution that does not involve a lambda function.

N.B. I know that the `ELU()` layer exists (an 'advanced activation function')  where I can set the value of `alpha` directly: `ELU(alpha=val)`, however I would like to know how to set the `alpha` parameter for an `Activation('elu')` layer.

I am using Python 2.7 and Keras 2.0.5.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the activation function outside you model and then add it like:

```
import keras

elu_activation = keras.activations.elu(x, alpha=0.9)


model = Sequential()
...
model.add(Dense(32 , activation=elu_activation))
...
```

[Here](https://keras.io/activations/) is a link to the docs

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. When calling `keras.activations.elu(x, alpha=0.9)` I get the error `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`, which does not seem surprising.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a lambda function:

```
from keras.activations import elu

custom_elu = lambda x: elu(x, alpha=0.4)
```

Then add `Activation(custom_elu)` to your model.

Comment: Apologies, I should have mentioned that I am looking for a solution that does not involve a lambda function. I will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
keras.layers.ELU(alpha=1.0)
```

https://keras.io/layers/advanced-activations/